# Get terms of a post but only if they're also the child of a specific term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have the below code successfully running on my custom post type archive pages. The only issue I have is that I want the list of 'book_cat' taxonomy terms for that post but ONLY if they're also children of the taxononmy term with an id of 5.

Trying to use the post ID as a parameter isn't working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0','taxonomy' => 'book_cat', 'child_of' => 5);
$categories = get_terms($args);
if($categories){
    echo '<ul class="characters">';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $link = get_term_link($category);
        echo '<li>';
        $size = "thumbnail";
        $image = get_field('main_image', 'category_'.$category->term_id);
        echo '<a href="'.$link.'">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'thumbnail', "", ["class" => "character"] );
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<span class="cat-title"><a href="'.$link.'">' . $category->name . '</a></span>';
        echo '</li>';
    } 
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, right now you get all child terms of term with id = 5, but you need to show only terms from this list, which are attached to the post.

> get_terms()
> Retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

Try to use `wp_get_post_terms()` instead, which allows you to set post id.
Make sure $post->ID is available.

> wp_get_post_terms()
> Retrieves the terms for a post.

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0','taxonomy' => 'book_cat', 'child_of' => 5);
$categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'book_cat', $args);
//rest of your code goes here.....
```

Comment: Actually, `wp_get_post_terms()`, although indirectly, also uses `get_terms()` and you can pass a post ID to `get_terms()` using the [`object_ids` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/), e.g. `get_terms( 'taxonomy=book_cat&object_ids=123' )`. But I'm not sure if @friendlyllama already tried that doing that.

Comment: Why it is inderectly?

Comment: `wp_get_post_terms()` uses [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) which is the one that calls `get_terms()`.

Comment: Ok, will keep in mind)